# CArray<TYPE,ARG_TYPE>' : base class undefined

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, mfc

I am going to create a new static lib in visual c++, with the use of an existing library.
I have copied an existing file from the old lib and added it to the newly created one.
((both header and cpp files)
The header file uses a file called QArray.h, so I copied that file too.
When building I am getting the errors below:

> error C2079: 'CDawesRun::m_HeadRatio'
>
> uses undefined class 'CArray'
>
> with
>
> [            TYPE=double,
>
> ARG_TYPE=double
>
> ]

What is the reason for this error?
I have created library as a Win32 static lib and have clicked the MFC option. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Compiler Error C2504](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw443zc0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). You are probably missing the #include where CArray is defined.

Also see [CArray Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4h2f09ct%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), CArray seems to be defined in afxtempl.h.

Comment: Thanks a lot user1610015. Include afxtempl.h solved the problem. :)